# Convert String to Integer without using parse or other methods

Tags: java, string, int

I am trying to convert a string to an integer, without using any built in methods like parseint(), do some calculation on the integer, and convert it back to string. Right now I can convert an integer to a string, but I need help turning the initial String to an integer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String s="1234";
     int i= (s)==1234;
     int i2=s/2 = 617;
     String s2=i2 = 617;

}
```

Comment: what are those lines supposed to do? All but the first line in the method will not compile.

Comment: And as always with these kind of very strange requests: *why*? What have you tried to achieve what you want and *why* do you even want that?

Comment: Its not actual code. am just trying to give an idea to the helpers of what im trying to accomplish. The description should help

Comment: 1. That is not actual code, Im trying to give an idea of what i need.
2. If i could use built-n methods I would not ask for help

Comment: @ luke, I just need to be able to convert a string to an integer without using built-in methods. That is literally all i need help with :)

Comment: And you have literally not shown any of your attempts at solving it on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Converting String to int without any library function**

```
public static int stringToInt(String number) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        res = res * 10 + number.charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    return res;
}
```

Perform whatever calculation you want to perform and then use the following method to convert the `int` back to `String` without any library function

**Converting int to String without any library function**

```
   public static String parseInt(int integer)
{
    boolean ifNegative = integer<0;
    boolean ifMin = integer == Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();        
    integer = ifNegative?(ifMin?Integer.MAX_VALUE:-integer):integer;    
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
    int remaining = integer;
    int currentDigit = 0 ;

    while(true)
    {
        currentDigit = remaining%10;
        list.add(currentDigit);
        remaining /= 10;
        if(remaining==0) break;
    }

    currentDigit = list.remove(0);
    builder.append(ifMin?currentDigit+1:currentDigit);
    for(int c : list)
        builder.append(c);
    builder.reverse().insert(0, ifNegative?'-':'+');
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [source code for `Integer.parseInt`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.parseInt%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29) is available on GrepCode. It uses a package-private method to generate `NumberFormatException` errors, but you can leave those out and the code will still work for valid strings.

```
public static int parseInt(String s, int radix) {
    int result = 0;
    boolean negative = false;
    int i = 0, len = s.length();
    int limit = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int multmin;
    int digit;

    if (len > 0) {
        char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
        if (firstChar < '0') {
            if (firstChar == '-') {
                negative = true;
                limit = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            }
            i++;
        }
        multmin = limit / radix;
        while (i < len) {
            digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++), radix);
            result *= radix;
            result -= digit;
        }
    }
    return negative ? result : -result;
}
```